# Remove /index from URL with functional mainpage

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-routing, domain-name

I am using the code below in .htaccess to remove .html from the end of file names and folder name, but the problem I'm facing is currently the website is only able to view with index or index.html.

The mainpage will shown only when I type
www.domain.it/index  or www.domain.it/index.html

**and will return to error 404 when i type www.domain.it

What should i do if I want the mainpage to be www.domain.it

> Options +MultiViews +FollowSymLinks 
>   RewriteEngine On 
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
>   RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L] 
>   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+pages/([^\s]+) [NC] 
>   RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L] 
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
>   RewriteRule (?!^pages/)^(.*)$ /pages/$1 [L,NC]